# Gcloud expose yii on LAMP stack

Tags: php, apache, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, lamp

How to expose yii2 basic or advanced project to localhost:80 on gcloud vm LAMP instance with numerical external address? Right now LAMP is running /var/www/shared and can pickup {exteralip}/phpmyadmin/ page.

`Yii2 start serve` start on localhost:8080

I can see `::1:8080 LISTEN` with `sudo netstat -ntlp`

And i opened firewall `0.0.0.0/0 tcp:8080` to test it, but `{externalip}:8080/` returns *connection refused*

How i could test yii2 and have it in gcloud?